# How to style a UITableViewCell different?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set a different style for my active object in a TableView. I tried setting a flag for my object (myObject.isActive) and read it in my custom UITableViewCell like this;

```
var myArray = [MyObject]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as? myCustomCell {
        if myArray.count > 0 {
            // Return the cell
            let myObject = myArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateUI(myObject: myObject)

            return cell
        }
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

myCustomCell:

```
func updateUI(myObject: MyObject){
    if myObject.isActive { 
        self.selectedCell()
    }
}

func selectedCell() {
    labelTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 32)
    labelTitle.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0x64BA00)
}
```

This works great when the tableView data loads. But when I scroll the tableView other cells are also styling differently. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cells get reused. You need to handle all possibilities. Your `updateUI` method changes the cell if `myObject` is active but you make no attempt to reset the cell if it isn't.

You need something like:

```
func updateUI(myObject: MyObject){
    if myObject.isActive { 
        selectedCell()
    } else {
        resetCell()
    }
}
```

And add:

```
func resetCell() {
    // Set the cell's UI as needed
}
```

Another options is to override the `prepareForReuse` method of the table cell class. That method should reset the cell to its initial state.